# AWK extract the shorter string in length from an array

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I have an array containing words such "gummy", "owl", "table" ... what I need is to extract the word shorter in length and assign it to a variable.

What I've tried

```
st[$1] = x;
for (i in st)
{
    if(min < st[i])
    {
        min = st[i];
    }
}
ld=min;
```

Comment: where is the array? Is it a bash array or an awk array? Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: @fedorqui Have you read the title of the question?, Have you read the tag?

Comment: According to the number of close votes on "unclear what you are asking", I am not the only one thinking so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for just finding the shortest length, consider this:

```
$ ./bar.awk
shortest= -1   i= 1    st[i]= gummy
first time, now shortest= 5
shortest= 5   i= 2    st[i]= owl
found shorter value, now shortest= 3
shortest= 3   i= 3    st[i]= table
shortest= 3   i= 4    st[i]= cat
done. shortest= 3

$ cat bar.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
   st[1]="gummy"
   st[2]="owl"
   st[3]="table"
   st[4]="cat"

   shortest = -1
   for (i in st)
   {
       print "shortest=", shortest, "  i=", i, "   st[i]=", st[i]
       if( shortest == -1 ) {
          shortest = length( st[i] )
          print "first time, now shortest=", shortest
       } else if( length( st[i] ) < shortest ) {
          shortest = length( st[i] )
          print "found shorter value, now shortest=", shortest
       }
   }
   print "done. shortest=", shortest
}
```

Original post:
Here's a short example, it should get you started.

I want to call out the use of printing things to see what the code is doing.  If you're not sure why something is working a particular way, add prints around it to display the values that are involved until you understand.  The printing doesn't need to be fancy or anything, just enough for you to understand what different expressions are doing what what a given variable happens to be at any point in time.

note 1: We start with candidate as an element in our array.  It is a little redundant because the loop will do an unecessary compare but it is easy to write this way, clear what is going on, and we avoid a possible error (what happens if you initialze candidate = "" and your array didn't have any empty string values?)

note 2: I'm assigning st[i] to a variable 'value' since I think that reads more clearly that st[i] everywhere (either way is fine).

```
$ chmod +x foo.awk
$ cat foo.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
   st[1]="gummy"
   st[2]="owl"
   st[3]="table"
   st[4]="cat"

   candidate=st[1]
   for (i in st)
   {
       print "candidate=", candidate
       print "        i=", i
       print "    st[i]=", st[i]
       value = st[i]
       if( length( value ) < length(candidate) )
       {
           candidate = value
           print "found shorter value, changing candidate=", candidate
       }
   }
   print "done. candidate=", candidate
}

$ ./foo.awk 
candidate= gummy
        i= 1
    st[i]= gummy
candidate= gummy
        i= 2
    st[i]= owl
found shorter value, changing candidate= owl
candidate= owl
        i= 3
    st[i]= table
candidate= owl
        i= 4
    st[i]= cat
done. candidate= owl
```

Question: Suppose you have two (or more) candidates that are all equally short, like "cat" and "owl" in the above example.  Which value(s) do you want to produce?  Can you think of a way to produce all of the shortest values ?

Comment: The array doesn't contain empty values, just I need to get the word shorter in length, no matter if that length is repeated. I just need to use the word length for later use in a substr () function

Comment: That's cool, i understand about never having "" (empty) values.  Does the example make sense?  It should work for what you're doing.  Since you're only after the shortest LENGTH, we can do better.... I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This script, which has been tested with several awks (including GNU awk and mawk), abstracts the desired functionality into an awk function.

```
# For each input line, this script splits the line into tokens
# in the usual (awkish) way and emits a token with minimal
# length if there are any, or otherwise the empty string.

awk '
  function minimalist(a, ix,min,n) {
    n=length(a);
    if (n==0) { return "";}
    ix=1; min=length(a[ix]); 
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) {
      if (length(a[i]) < min) {
        ix=i; min=length(a[ix]);
      }
    }
    return a[ix];
  }

  { n=split($0, a);
    answer = minimalist(a);
    print answer;
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution with bash build-ins.

```
$ a=(gummy owl table) 
$ for i in ${a[@]}; do echo ${#i} $i; done | sort -n | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2

owl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    array["gummy"]
    array["owl"]
    array["table"]

    for (word in array) {
        cur = length(word)
        if ( (min == 0) || (cur < min) ) {
            shortest = word
            min = cur
        }
    }

    print shortest
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
owl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to invoke the `length` function:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  st[1] = "gummy"
  st[2] = "owl"
  st[3] = "table"

  for (i in st)
  {
    if (min == "" || length (st[i]) < length (min))
    {
      min = st[i]
    }
  }

  print min

}
'
```

Results:

```
owl
```